# load xml file in android at dynamic time

Tags: android

I am trying to parse some text at run time. I am new to android any help would be appreciated.

I wanted to parse text and put that in a image view. I am doing this:

```
try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                "http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
    sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

    /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
    name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
    website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
    category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

    /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
    for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
        name[i] = new TextView(this);
        name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));
        website[i] = new TextView(this);
        website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
        category[i] = new TextView(this);
        category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));

        layout.addView(name[i]);
        layout.addView(website[i]);
        layout.addView(category[i]);
    }
```

Comment: So where do you stuck, or what is your problem

Comment: At looking at your code first thing i would suggest you to use [AsyncTask](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.UsUCGvQW0qI)

Comment: where is your problem you should tell, fetching data or rendering it on image view ?

Comment: i want to place my own xml url in place of url http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml